# OOP Python - arguments in __self__ (budget app)

Tags: python

Could somebody explain me difference between these two pieces of code? I know that in the second case the arguments can be passed while instansiating the object but my problem was that when I used the 2 option, then the ledger list contained all objects that I have created. With the first one list is unique for the object as expected.

1. ```
   def __init__(self, category):

    self.category = category
    self.ledger = []
    self.balance = 0.0
   ```
2. ```
   def __init__(self, category, ledger = [], balance = 0.0):

    # Assign self to object
    self.category = category
    self.ledger = ledger
    self.balance = balance
   ```

Comment: Relevant doc: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions. "the expression is evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call."

Comment: `ledger = None,` in arguments then `self.ledger = ledger or []`